# Preserve metadata while sending and receiving data from kni interface in dpdk

Tags: networking, sdn, dpdk

Is there a way to preserve metadata or any equivalent data while sending and receiving mbuf to and from kni interface in dpdk??
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are asking for an out of the box solution, then no there is no such functionality. Only length and frame content get copied to/from the host kernel. For more information please see kni_net_tx/rx() functions in kni_net.c:
http://dpdk.org/browse/dpdk/tree/lib/librte_eal/linuxapp/kni/kni_net.c#n202

But sure, you can add whatever you want to each mbuf passing from/to kernel. The only requirement is that you have to change both user-space (i.e. DPDK lib/librte_kni) and kernel-space (i.e. lib/librte_eal/linuxapp/kni) to support the metadata you need.